# Vim prints meaningless error

Tags: vim, vundle

When I load vim I get the following message that I cannot figure out how to debug.

```
4FNVHQ1|tmp
λ vim
default
Press ENTER or type command to continue
4FNVHQ1|tmp
λ
```

I've run `vim -V9myVimLog` and got this in the output but there's still nothing useful to me.

```
....
chdir(/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 5: sourcing "/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle/config.vim"
finished sourcing /c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle/config.vim
continuing in function vundle#rc
                                default
Searching for "filetype.vim" in "/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-coffee-script,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-jade,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/nerdtree,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-rails,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-commentary,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-rake,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/snipMate,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/bsh.vim,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-csharp,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-distinguished,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/surround.vim,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/jshint2.vim,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-ps1,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/MatchTag,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/VCard-syntax,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-liquid,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-jst,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-stylus,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-swigjs,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/xmledit,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-less,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-markdown,/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-nerdtree-tabs,/c/Use
Searching for "/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/c/Users/bjones/.vim/bundle/vim-coffee-script/filetype.vim"
....
```

As you can see the word "default" is printed awkwardly in the debug log but there's nothing helpful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: My vimrc is here: https://gist.github.com/brettof86/9906968

**EDIT2 [FIX?]**: IDK how it made a difference but I commented out every "Bundle" command in my vimrc then saved and quit. Then I went back and uncommented them 5 at a time and it started working? I have no idea why it was broken but I hope this helps anyone who may also run into this issue.

Comment: Seems like it is trying to print a carriage return.

Comment: Could you share your config?

Comment: @romainl added it to the OP

Comment: The 'default' is the output of the command 'colors' which is there in your vimrc line #55. I believe that should be commented.

Comment: @DhruvaSagar you're absolutely right. I accidentally uncommented that line before and when I went through and toggled them all I corrected it. Thanks! BTW add that as an answer and I'll select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistakenly added an extra line `colors` in your vimrc, that as an VIM Ex command outputs the current selected colorscheme and since you haven't defined one yet, it outputs `default` since that is, as the name suggests, the default VIM colorscheme. You should comment it out since it clearly appears to be a documenting comment rather than executing an Ex command.